# How to change extracted images location in html document created with pandoc?

Tags: html, pandoc, epub

am using pandoc to convert epub files to html but am having trouble with certain epub books who use /images folder for images and or other media.

Example:

```
pandoc -s --extract-media=bw_files bw.epub -o bw.html -M document-css=false
```

would create an bw_files folder with extracted images folder in it but goal is to move them and change location for them in outputted html document to / so the image files are properly referenced.

Comment: the command you posted includes the images for me with pandoc 2.11.3 and some random epub I had lying around... perhaps it depends on the epub? btw. out of curiosity: why do you set `document-css=false` without supplying your own CSS with `--css`? Do you want unstyled HTML for some reason?

Answer (score 2):

The following call may help you:

```
pandoc -s --extract-media=. bw.epub -o bw.html -c my-style.css
```

Please note that the subfolder `bw_files` from your example will not be created. But the structure of the .epub file will be extracted. The result depends on the internal structure of the .epub file.

For further information please have a look at [Wikipedia EPUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB).

Answer (score 1):

The images go into pandoc's "mediabag" during conversion. Their filenames
can be modified there, as can the links to the images. The Lua filter
below does just that; save the filter to a file, then pass that file to pandoc
via `--lua-filter`.

```lua
local mediabag = require 'pandoc.mediabag'

-- Delete image files and re-insert under new name
for fp, mt, contents in mediabag.items() do
  mediabag.delete(fp)
  mediabag.insert(fp:gsub('images/', ''), mt, contents)
end

-- adjust path to image file
function Image (img)
  img.src = img.src:gsub('images/', '')
  return img
end
```

This is a copy of an answer which I gave on the pandoc mailing list.